# Sorting an array via user defined function

Tags: php, arrays

I want a user defined function for sorting a multi dimension array:

```
<?php
$arr1 = array(
    49,
    8,
    array(
        'Muazam',
        'Ali',
        'Rana',
        'Amina',
        'Surya',
        'Danish',
        'Raina',
        4,
        3,
        2,
        1,
    ) ,
    7,
    6,
    5,
    4,
    3,
    2,
    1,
    0,
);

function abc($arr)
    {
    $len = count($arr) - 2;
    foreach($arr as $key => $value)
        {
        for ($a = 0; $a <= $len; $a++)
            {
            if ($arr[$a] > $arr[$a + 1])
                {
                $temp4 = $arr[$a];
                $arr[$a] = $arr[$a + 1];
                $arr[$a + 1] = $temp4;
                }
            }

        if (is_array($value))
            {
            abc($value, $a = $a + 1);
            }
        }
    } //2nd foreach close
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: You should use `usort`

Comment: With which criteria do you want to sort your array? What is the current output and what do you expect to get?

Comment: `function abc(&$arr)` pass array as reference if you want to edit it inplace. However im not sure what you are trying to do here - the recursive call to the function is attempting to pass a second parameter to the function, though it only accepts a single parameter

Comment: In out put the function sorts inner array at first but I want it in a organised way...

Comment: Have you came across `array_filter()`

Comment: basically I want to sort a multidimensional array by using recursive... hav you any idea about it?? I just want user defined function... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic usage of a recursive function:

```
$arr1 = array(49, 8, array(
    'Muazam', 'Ali', 'Rana', 'Amina', 'Surya', 'Danish', 'Raina', 4, 3, 2, 1,
), 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0);

function recursiveSort(&$array)
{
    foreach ($array as &$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            recursiveSort($value);
        }
    }

    return sort($array);
}

recursiveSort($arr1);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr1);
echo '</pre>';
```

The result would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 7
    [8] => 8
    [9] => 49
    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ali
            [1] => Amina
            [2] => Danish
            [3] => Muazam
            [4] => Raina
            [5] => Rana
            [6] => Surya
            [7] => 1
            [8] => 2
            [9] => 3
            [10] => 4
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Is Answer.. Sorting a multi dimensional array without using built in function.

```
$arr1 = array(1,3,5,'2',array(99,55,array(111,444,array('a','r','p','e','t'),777),66,99),8,9,0,3,1);
function abc(&$arr)
{
$len=count($arr)-2;
foreach($arr as $key => &$value)
   {
for ($a=0;$a<=$len;$a++){

if($arr[$a]>$arr[$a+1])
{

  $temp4=$arr[$a];
  $arr[$a]=$arr[$a+1];
  $arr[$a+1]=$temp4;
}

}

if(is_array($value))
              {

               abc($value,$a=$a+1); 
              }

    }//foreach close

//}//2nd foreach close

    echo "<pre>";
    return $arr;
    echo "</pre>";

}//function close




 print_r (abc($arr1));
```